Installer: Create LVM volume group screen does not show me partitions
I am trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 on a server with existing partitions. I am using the custom partitioning screen, first deleting all the old partitions, selected to reformat the disks and started adding partitions.
I created an unformatted partition to create a volume group on, but when I select the "Create volume group (LVM)", the partition selection is "blind", I can select partitions, but I don't know what I am selecting:

